# Gráfica con Chart.js y Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, chart.js

Requiero hacer una gráfica con Chart.js, integrando unos datos de MySql de una tabla que maneja varios campos entre ellos "fecha" y "estado", y la columna estado maneja valores 1, 2 o 3.
La idea es tener una gráfica que cuente el total de registros con el estado 1, 2 y 3 de cada mes, de los últimos 6 meses.
Para esto tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['nombre'];
$_SESSION['nivel'];
$_SESSION['acceso'];
if (!$_SESSION) {
  header('Location: /index.php');
}
require '../includes/conecta_servidor.php';
$db = conectarDB();

$id = $_SESSION['acceso'];

// Escribir Query de historico cartera
$consultafc = "SELECT fecha, COUNT(estado) total FROM pqr WHERE cliente = $id 
GROUP BY estado 
HAVING COUNT(estado)=1
HAVING COUNT(estado)=2
HAVING COUNT(estado)=3
LIMIT 6";
// Consultar la DB para resultados
$resultadofc = mysqli_query($db, $consultafc);
$chart_data = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadofc)) {
    $fecha[] = $row['fecha'];
    $estado[] = $row['estado'];
};
?>
```

La idea es que al finalizar se muestre un gráfico como el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Requiero su valiosa ayuda para bajar los datos de la consulta al gráfico.

Comment: No entiendo, cual es la pregunta o problema?

Comment: Pues.. no se como pasar los datos de la consulta de la DB a la gráfica de chart.js

Comment: @Yussef no se como pasar los datos de Mysql a una gráfica dinámica con chart.js

Comment: ivan no entiendo tu postura, cual puede ser el motivo de no aceptar las respuesta si a ti no te cuesta nada y contribuye al sitio que estas usando

Comment: Venga... digame cual respueste no puntee y listo... no se de cual me hablan...

Comment: No te estoy obligando a aceptar las respuesta, te pregunto el motivo de no hacerlo. Tu decides si aceptar o no. El punto es que tienes respuestas donde has indicado vía comentario que es correcta pero no la has aceptado. Se te ha explicado al menos 3 veces como hacerlo